# CentOS 7 image naming conventions

Tags: centos, linux-kernel, disk-image

I'm looking at the following on CentOS 7:

```
boot$ ls
config-3.10.0-229.7.2.el7.x86_64
config-3.10.0-229.el7.x86_64
grub
grub2
initramfs-0-rescue-9fde7dd9a7884e1b8fdef68620955b36.img
initramfs-3.10.0-229.7.2.el7.x86_64.img
initramfs-3.10.0-229.el7.x86_64.img
initrd-plymouth.img
symvers-3.10.0-229.7.2.el7.x86_64.gz
symvers-3.10.0-229.el7.x86_64.gz
System.map-3.10.0-229.7.2.el7.x86_64
System.map-3.10.0-229.el7.x86_64
vmlinuz-0-rescue-9fde7dd9a7884e1b8fdef68620955b36
vmlinuz-3.10.0-229.7.2.el7.x86_64
vmlinuz-3.10.0-229.el7.x86_64
```

Are `3.10.0-229.7.2.el7.x86_64` and `3.10.0-229.el7.x86_64` different (the former has an extra `7.2` in the name)?

If they are the same, then what is the difference in the name?

If they are different, then what is the difference? And which one is newer?

---

This is my first time on CentOS. I set up the machine so I could do a `git clone` and ensure a library build under it. I don't have altruistic intentions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They're different and 7.2 is newer.

3.10.0-229.el7 is the original release, 3.10.0-229.7.2.el7 is security update/bug fixes.

Please refer to redhat's release note page:

kernel-3.10.0-229.1.2.el7
https://rhn.redhat.com/errata/RHSA-2015-0726.html

kernel-3.10.0-229.7.2.el7
https://rhn.redhat.com/errata/RHSA-2015-1137.html

Comment: Perfect, thanks. I'm low on VM space, and I was trying to determine if I could delete one of them and run `grub-mkconfig` to update the menu.